# React-Native with macos target

Tags: ios, macos, react-native

Trying to create a NEW project which targets -both- macos and ios/android seems to fail.

Steps:

1. Followed steps on react native website, using create-react-native-app to get a native application. It works fine.
2. Use react-native-macos init and macos to get the mac app - it also works fine.
3. Noticing that #1 uses an App.js and #2 uses some sort of index.platform.js model, I change the xcode project in #2 to look for App.js instead. This at least makes sure the same code is reached.
4. As the react-native-macos github page says to do, I merge #2 into #1.. (unclear whether should overwriting, used 'ditto' command)
5. Add the rn-cli.config.js file to root, as react-native-macos says to do
6. Missing modules when I try to run macos - fails to bundle.

It looks to me like the 'react-native' folder in the node modules is somehow screwing up the react-native-macos folder. I'm still trying a variety of things but it's been exhausting considering how easy 'merge into your existing project' sounds.

https://github.com/ptmt/react-native-macos <- what i want to merge in

Comment: as background im an experienced titanium developer switching over and I wanted to start with an app that could also target desktop if possible, to surmise whether it is the choice solution for my company's current needs :) So yes, newbie at react, very familiar with cross-platform mobile

Answer (score 3):

You likely will not be able to use `create-react-native-app` and `react-native-macos` together without some trail and error. This is because `create-react-native-app` actually creates an `Expo` app which is built on top of `react-native` but tries to abstract away a lot of the native details from the end user. For example you can't use any native modules that are not shipped with `Expo` when using `create-react-native-app`. The documentation of `react-native-macos` is likely assuming you are using `react-native init` which creates a base `react-native` project that you have to handle building on your own instead of offloading the build process to `Expo`.